# Different CUDA results when running from menu mode and terminal mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch, virtual-environment

I have a simple test.py code like below in vscode:

```
import torch
# check if pytorch is using cuda/gpu
print("CUDA available: ", torch.cuda.is_available())
```

and the following settings.json

```
{
    "python.venvPath": "/Users/myname/Anaconda3/envs",
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda3\\envs\\pytorch\\python.exe"
}
```

I have installed cpu version of pytorch in the base conda, and a virtual environment named "pytorch" with regular/gpu version of pytorch installed.

Now when I ran the code from terminal with: python test.py, I had results:

```
CUDA available:  False
```

While if I ran the code from menu, either using start debugging (F5) or run without debugging (Ctrl+F5), results were both:

```
CUDA available:  True
```

What's the problem? and how to use CUDA in terminal mode?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Before typing 'python test.py' in the terminal, have you activated the venv? Press Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new terminal and type 'python test.py'  again, then check the results.

Comment: @MollyWang Yes I tried. My terminal in VSCode seems to be PS, and activating the venv doesn't change it in the terminal window, not like in other Anaconda Prompt window that activating venv will give us the new environment's name in from of the command line. and I got the same result of False CUDA. Not sure how to let the venv name show in my terminal.

Comment: Issue solved by choosing 'cmd prompt' as terminal option, and activating the virtual environment.